# Change subnetmask in linux

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, netmask

How can I change the subnetmask of my eth0 interface?

```
sudo ifconfig netmask 255.255.254.0
```

I tried this but it wasn't effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you lose `device` parameter.

Just like this:

```sh
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.120.56 netmask 255.255.254.0
```

Then restart your network service

```sh
systemctl restart network
```

Comment: `systemctl` is not very portable.
I did `sudo ifconfig eth0 down; sudo ifconfig eth0 up` instead.